# mongo template to query a array of document

Tags: java, mongodb, mongotemplate

I have read the mongo manual 3.6.It has a example json--The bios ExampleCollection, like this:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : {
        "first" : "John",
        "last" : "Backus"
    },
    "birth" : ISODate("1924-12-03T05:00:00Z"),
    "death" : ISODate("2007-03-17T04:00:00Z"),
    "contribs" : [
        "Fortran",
        "ALGOL",
        "Backus-Naur Form",
        "FP"
    ],
    "awards" : [
        {
            "award" : "W.W. McDowell Award",
            "year" : 1967,
            "by" : "IEEE Computer Society"
        },
        {
            "award" : "National Medal of Science",
            "year" : 1975,
            "by" : "National Science Foundation"
        },
        {
            "award" : "Turing Award",
            "year" : 1977,
            "by" : "ACM"
        },
        {
            "award" : "Draper Prize",
            "year" : 1993,
            "by" : "National Academy of Engineering"
        }
    ]
}
```

According by the manual, To Query an Array of Documents, QL like this:

```
db.bios.find(
   {
      awards: {
                $elemMatch: {
                     award: "Turing Award",
                     year: { $gt: 1980 }
                }
      }
   }
)
```

I use spring mongo template to query this document using above express:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria( Criteria.where("awards").elemMatch( 
Criteria.where("award").is("Turing Award").and("year").gt(new Integer(1980))) );
List<TestEntity> list = mongoTemplate.find(query, TestEntity.class, "testentity");
Assert.assertTrue(!list.isEmpty());
//testentity is a collection in my local db to store example json text.
```

I don't understand why the result list is empty. I debug the last statement and watch the query variable. It's string format is:

```
Query: { "awards" : { "$elemMatch" : { "award" : "Turing Award" , "year" : { "$gt" : 1980}}}}, Fields: null, Sort: null
```

and copy

```
{ "awards" : { "$elemMatch" : { "award" : "Turing Award" , "year" : { "$gt" : 1980}}}}
```

to robo 3T mongo client tool query. it query 3 results. How does the java code work?
                                           thank you.

Comment: you don't have any element matching the query.

Comment: It would help if you actually showed a document that matched the result. The query looks good, so I can only imagine that your code is connecting to somewhere different to where you are running the query to test.

Comment: The sample is snippet of entire BIOS json text, only show it's structs. see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bios-example-collection/

I want to know why doesn't work java code,but same query it done in mongo client

Comment: as @GaganChouhan say, it' ok now. I query in another db configed in application.properties. The db collection only have one document, and it don't match with this query.   thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
{
    "award" : "Turing Award",
    "year" : 1977,
    "by" : "ACM"
},
```

to

```
 {
    "award" : "Turing Award",
    "year" : 1981,
    "by" : "ACM"
 }
```